# Is it safe to use a baby carrier worn on the back to carry an 11-month-old?

Tags: infant, safety, transport

My baby is 11 months old. His weight is 9.5kg. Is it safe to use a baby carrier worn on the back to carry him?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're talking about a baby carrier, **Yes.** You can wear an 11 month old on your back.

Some details:

- It is recommended by [Babywearing International](http://babywearinginternational.org/what-is-babywearing/safety/) that you wait until a baby can sit unassisted or with minimal assistance before putting him or her on your back. This is because being able to sit indicates a level of neck & trunk control that means you don't have to worry about the baby's airway being compromised.
- Use the baby carrier as recommended by the manufacturer. If the carrier says that it cannot be used on the back, believe it.
- Some popular examples of buckle carriers that can be used on that back, called soft structured carriers or SSCs by the pros, are the [Ergo](http://blog.ergobaby.com/2012/05/the-back-carry-safe-easy-practical/), [Beco](https://www.becobabycarrier.com/cat-13/gemini), and [Tula](http://www.tulababycarriers.com/collections/ergonomic-baby-carriers).
- Hiking backpacks, that hold the baby away from the body of the adult, are also safe to use at this age, but tend to be much more involved and less cozy. Some love them for longer treks. A good example of this type of carrier is a [Kelty](https://kelty.com/kids/).
- You can also wear your baby in a non-backpack type carrier, such as a [woven](http://babywearinginternational.org/what-is-babywearing/babywearing-resources/intermediate-and-advanced-back-carries/) or a [mei tai](http://babywearinginternational.org/what-is-babywearing/babywearing-resources/mei-tai/), but these have a higher learning curve.

Enjoy wearing your baby!